# discord.py; Warn/Strike system

Tags: python, discord.py

I am pretty new to discord.py, and making a bot for a personal server, and my warn command hasn't been working. This is what I currently have:

```
@client.command()
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        if str(channel) == "moderation-logs":
            embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=0x00FFFF)
            embed.set_footer(text="Olympia Gaming | Manual Moderation")
        warnid = random.randint(9000000000, 12000000000000)
        post = {
            "guild": ctx.guild.id,
            "member": member.id,
            "warnid": warnid,
            "moderator": ctx.message.author.name,
            "reason": reason,
            "date": str(ctx.message.created_at)
            }

        msg.author = ctx.message.author 
        if member.top_role < msg.author.top_role:
            collection.insert_one(post)
            embed.set_author(name=f"{member} has been succesfully warned!", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/690937143522099220/34fbd058360c3d4696848592ff1c5191.webp?size=1024")
            embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f"{reason}")
            embed.add_field(name="Warn ID:", value=f"{warnid}")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            await member.send(embed=embed)
            embed.add_field(name="Staff Member:", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}({ctx.author.id})")  
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
        elif msg.author.id == ctx.guild.owner_id:
            if msg.author.id == member.id:
                await ctx.send(f" You need your role higher than {member.name}'s to execute this command. ")
            else:
                collection.insert_one(post)
                embed.set_author(name=f"{member} has been succesfully warned!", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/690937143522099220/34fbd058360c3d4696848592ff1c5191.webp?size=1024")
                embed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f"{reason}")
                embed.add_field(name="Warn ID:", value=f"{warnid}")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                await member.send(embed=embed)
                embed.add_field(name="Staff Member:", value=f"{ctx.author.mention}({ctx.author.id})")  
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f" You need your role higher than {member.name}'s to execute this command. ")
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'embed' referenced before assignment
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the channel isn't the moderation channel, `embed` doesnt exist. You have to move the `embed = blah` outside of that for loop so the rest of the function can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
    if str(channel) == "moderation-logs":
        embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=0x00FFFF)
        embed.set_footer(text="Olympia Gaming | Manual Moderation")
```

I assume that, if the channel is a different one, you desire for nothing else to happen for that loop iteration. You need, therefore, to use `continue` to skip it explicitly.

Better yet, you could first do a loop that *just* finds the correct `channel`, and then proceed with the rest of the logic *outside* that loop. I am assuming here that exactly one of the `ctx.guild.channels` is the one you want. Maybe you can do even better, i.e., directly look it up. Try reading the documentation some more.